# Characterisation for real analytic function vis Fourier coefficient

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

A $C^{\infty}$ function on $\mathbb R$ is real analytic if for every $x\in \mathbb R$,  $f$ is the sum of its Taylor series expansion bases at  $x$ in some neighbourhood of $x$.

If $f$ is periodic we may regard $f$ as a function on $S=\{z\in \mathbb C: |z|=1\}$, this condition is equivalent to the condition that $f$ be the restriction on $S$ of a holomorphic function on some neighbourhood of $S.$ (Why?)

Also, how to show that $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb T)$ is real analytic iff $|\hat{f}(k)|\leq C e^{-\epsilon |k|}$ for some $C>0$ and $\epsilon>0.$

Comment: By "this condition", do you mean "$f$ is analytic"? Also, in your final line, you have not defined $\Bbb T,  \hat f$, or $k$, though presumably you mean $\forall k \in \Bbb T$.

Comment: As for your "why", consider that any Real power series is also a complex power series if you just let the variable take on complex values.